# Like Star half pyramid pattern with URL Path

Tags: php, arrays, loops, directory

**I guarante this Different than normally Store to Array.**

I dont know how to name it in Tittle about what im asked !!

First : sorry for Bad English.
So just see this below ...

Second :

a. im use build in server : php artisan serve

b. framework is Laravel 5.4

I have url http://127.0.0.1:8000/file/999090/img/img-2as

```
host        : 127.0.0.1:8000 etc

main-folder : {/file} Where i store my image

folder-id   : {/990909} This is just id for each folder

sub-folder  : {/img} Each id has many sub folder [example]

filde-name  : {/img2-as} Just file name [example]
```

So this is question :
I wanna have array like this in PHP :

```
$array = [ 
    0 => '/file',
    1 => '/file/990909',
    2 => '/file/990909/img',
    3 => '/file/990909/img/img-2as'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $root = '/'; // !!! CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR OWN FOLDER!!!

    $iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
    );

    $paths = array($root);
    foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
        if ($dir->isDir()) {
            $paths[] = $path;
        }
    }

    print_r($paths);
```

Comment: I got error like this in my Laravel : RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/file,/file): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

Comment: $root = '/';
what folder did you provided it??

Comment: '/file'. Did that must have Really folder with a file inside ? if yes pardon me.

Comment: yes! you can add this check
` $root = '/'; // !!! CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR OWN FOLDER!!!
if(is_dir($root){
    $iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
    );

    $paths = array($root);
    foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
        if ($dir->isDir()) {
            $paths[] = $path;
        }
    }

    print_r($paths);
} else echo "Invalid Dir";`

Comment: This is my link http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/theme/dist/img/img/user2-160x160.jpg and i get invalid dir. I already open it and image alredy show. But still i get invalid dir.

Comment: You know that that is local host ip you are sending us,.... that is not usefull for us

Comment: Hey thank for advice, but this just for practice. I already found it.

Answer (score 0):

I already manage just like this :

```
$parts = "assets/theme/dist/img//img/user2-160x160.jpg";
$path  = explode('/', $parts);
for($i=0;$i<count($path);$i++){
  for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++){
    echo "/".$path[$j];
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

And result is :

/assets

/assets/

/assets/theme/dist

/assets/theme/dist/img

/assets/theme/dist/img/

/assets/theme/dist/img/img

That is what i want have in array and i already try use array_push, but the result is worse.

Answer (score 0):

Im already found it. Just copy in your php file.

```
$path     = "assets/adminlte/dist/img/user2-160x160";
$asd      = explode( '/', $path );

$num      = count($asd)-1;
$arr      = [];

for($i=0;$i<count($asd);$i++) {
    for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++){
        @$arr[$i] .= "/".$asd[$j];
    }
}

echo "\n";

print_r($arr);
```